# os.environ doesn't find actual file path after pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pyinstaller, python-cryptography

I basically need to access `filekey.key` which is in the same directory of both the python file and the pyinstalled executable. I know I have to handle properly the file location so that I'm checking for _MEIPASS2. But it doesn't work.

I'm also using `--onefile`. Code is more eloquent.

**Python file**

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
filename = 'filekey.key' 
if '_MEIPASS2' in os.environ:
    filename = os.path.join(os.environ['_MEIPASS2'], filename)

with open(filename, 'rb') as filekey:
    key = filekey.read()
```

I've also tried using a batch file to launch it but no success.

**ERROR when running .exe**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launch.py", line 7, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filekey.key'
```

Comment: did you try to set the cwd explicitly; e.g. `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)`?

Comment: I didn't. That solved the issue! Thanks